# Django model validation on related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-validation

When is the appropriate time to do validation on related fields in a model?

For example if I have a class Video that has a `ManyToMany` relationship with a class Playlist, when the Video is changed to 'private', it should be removed from all Playlists.

Doing this in the model's `clean()` method seems dangerous - since the model might fail validation and not save, but the Playlist references will have been deleted.

Is doing it in a `post_save` or `pre_save` signal the right way to go?

Comment: Seems like a good idea, or you could overwrite the save method (lesser good idea IMHO).

Comment: I would do this is a post_save signal.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

First one is using a `post_save` signal that does the job. Not a `pre_save`, because saving can fail and I guess you only want to do that if the save worked right.

Other option is overriding model's `save()` method like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # do stuff for removing whatever you want to remove
```

My personal choice is the first one because you deal with different models. If you only need to deal with the current one, I'll do the second one. But it's just a personal thought.